# Not possible to load origin data in st.data_editor of streamlit in python

Tags: python, streamlit

Summary

Hi all. I created a CRUD-App, where I want to establish a “reset” function to load the original data back to the st.data_editor, after some modifications were done. (e.g.
You see below, that I use st.cache_data in a separate function to call data from a mysql-database. For this example I use hard coded data - but it´s the same procedure.

Code snippet:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

# Create a DataFrame

if st.button("Clear to origin"):
    st.cache_data.clear()

@st.cache_data
def dat_query():
    print("cleared")
    dat = pd.DataFrame([
        {"x": 1, "y": 0},
        {"x": 2, "y": 0},
        {"x": 3, "y": 0},
        {"x": 4, "y": 0}])
    return dat

df = dat_query()

df_ed = st.data_editor(df)
```

If I click “Clear to origin”, I would expect that the data_editor will be initialized with the old data and I see the old data in the web app. The function dat_query is called as expected, but the st.data_editor does not show the original data.

Actual behavior:

The original data will never be shown in the st.data_editor

Comment: solution can be found here:
https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/not-possible-to-load-origin-data-in-st-data-editor/51938